# Create List of Items in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on VS 2013 Cordova App . I want to create new list of items by jquery . here is my Html code :

```
<div class="body" >
    <ul class="list list-messages" id="list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my js code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: 'http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/data/getalllocations',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#list").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#list").append('<li class="list-message" data-ix="list-item"><a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block" href="chat.html" data-load="1"><div class="w-clearfix column-left"><div class="image-message"><img src="images/128.jpg"></div></div><div class="column-right"><div class="message-title">James White</div><div class="message-text">Hey dude! We are waiting for you at the main station, we will meet you near to....</div></div></a></li>');

                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it dosen't work with me , Please advice

Comment: What is not working? Did you debug and see where it is failing? IS there an error in the console? Is the Ajax call returning? Is your selector finding the element?

Comment: No, there is no errors .but it seems that it append list items but it not appear . I don't know why . but the page is scrolling .

Comment: So if you add `console.log(data);` you see an array. If you add `console.log($("#list"));` you see an unordered list.  So when you add `console.log(i);` inside the for loop you see that? Now if you do not see the first log message, add an error handle to the Ajax call.

Comment: It is working without ajax

Comment: Sounds like you Ajax call is not working... So add an erorr handler to it and see if it is triggered. `success: function () {}, error: console.log(arguments); }`

Comment: Try to adding `dataType : 'json'` to the AJAX call.

Comment: I have add alert to show data . alert(data[i].LocationName) in for loop but it is working fine .

Comment: Are you trying do a cross-domain AJAX call?

Answer (score 1):

For starters you have two #list ids, try removing the id from the div.

You should never had two id's the same.

Furthermore, change the append and empty to the class ".list" and remove both ID's

Comment: yes its fault but it is not the error .  it seems that it append list items but it not appear . I don't know why . but the page is scrolling

Comment: Console.log the **$('.list').html();** after the for loop, might give an insight.